# Remove white 'flash' effect when fading background images jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get rid of the white flash of background color when fading background images. I'd like the images just to fade in/out of each other.

Here's my jQuery, HTML and CSS code

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(window).load(function() {          
          var i =0;
          var images = ['assets/img/cake_2.jpg','assets/img/cake_3.jpg', 'assets/img/cake_1.jpg'];
          var image = $('#wrapper');
                        //Initial Background image setup
          image.css('background-image', 'url(assets/img/cake_1.jpg)');
                        //Change image at regular intervals
          setInterval(function(){  
           image.fadeOut(6000, function () {
           image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images [i++] +')');
           image.fadeIn(6000);
           });
           if(i == images.length)
            i = 0;
          }, 1000);           
});
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width:              100%;
    height:             100%;
    margin:             0 auto;
    z-index:            -1;
    position:           absolute;
    overflow:           hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are fading out the current image completely before the next image starts to fade in. This causes the white background at the middle of animation. Here is a solution:

- Place a div containing the *next* image behind the currently visible div using absolute positioning and z-index
- Fadeout the *current* div

In this way, the current image will fade into the next image smoothly.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var i = 0;
    var images = [
        'http://dummyimage.com/300x200/FC0/000&text=Slide+1',
        'http://dummyimage.com/300x200/CF0/000&text=Slide+2',
        'http://dummyimage.com/300x200/0FC/000&text=Slide+3'];
    $('#wrapper').css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i] + ')');
    setInterval(function () {
        if (++i === images.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        console.log(i);
        $('#nextimg').css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i] + ')');
        // transition animation: 2s
        $('#wrapper').fadeOut(2000, function () {
            $('#wrapper').css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i] + ')').show();
        });
        // slide change: 3s
    }, 3000);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zq39xpgx/1/)

Comment: so if I had three images the z-indexes could be `-1` `-2` `-3` and have them fade consistently in a loop?

Comment: Ideally I would create one div per img and use z-index. I would avoid negative z-indexes, they do not work as expected across browsers as far as I remember.

Comment: I have added a jsFiddle

Comment: You're very close with the jsFiddle but that pushes all my content below the two images.

Comment: Modifying your solution but you pointed me in the right direction, correct answer :)